# how to check if a number I try to add already exist in the column and row?(2d arrays )

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
int [][]a=new int[9][9] //creates a "square" with 81 0's
```

How do I go about checking if a input (when filling out the array) already exist in the column or row?
For example, for the row 0, how can I make sure I don't get the number 9 two times (for instance, once on row 0, column 0 and second on row 0 column 1)? I can't seem to figure out how to go about this (all I know is that I'll probably need two `for` loops? and a `if` statement. I'm not sure how to go about the `if` statement tho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] a = new int[9][9];
    boolean areThereDuplicates;

    int input = 9; // or any input of course
    int row = 0;   // or any row
    int column = 0;// or any column

    areThereDuplicates = checkDuplicates(input, row, column, a);

    if (!areThereDuplicates) // if there are no duplicates, input value
        a[row][column] = input;
}

public static boolean checkDuplicates(int numChecked, int row, int column, int[][] arr)
{
    // checks row
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[row].length; j++)
    {
        if (arr[row][j] == numChecked)
            return true;
    }

    // checks column
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
    {
        if (arr[k][column] == numChecked)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

One important thing I wanted to point out is the for loop that checks the column. `arr.length` does not return 81; rather it returns 9. `arr[row].length` also returns how many columns there are in the specified `row`.

Comment: numChecked is simply the input "number to be checked". In this particular case, I set input to 9 for your example and input = numChecked. So the method will check if the array has the number 9 in the same row or column specified.

Answer (score 0):

Quick draft, not tested but should work:

```
a[x][y] = newValue; // e.g. 9
return checkDuplicates(x, y, newValue); // returns true if a duplicate is found

public boolean checkDuplicates(int x, int y, int newValue) {
  for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (i!=x && a[i][y]==newValue)
      return true;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (i!=y && a[x][i]==newValue)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: quick thinking: can't you just use only 1 loop and reuse it to validate both row and column? Note 2: won't work, this code is for javascript, not java.

Comment: @abpoir123 If `a` is a local variable inside `main`, `checkDuplicates` won't be able to see it.  You'll either need to pass the array as an `int[][]` parameter to `checkDuplicates`, or take it out of `main` and make it a class member.